# How to render multiple files in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to make my own website based on python flask and the content will be about space and and using Nasa's Api
I have three files index.html, nasa.js, starfield.js
I have to render all these files to my flask program
I have tried doing all the methods in the internet
Can you please advice what to do
All the code is in the link below:
index.html - https://pastebin.com/miVx2FZb `index.html`
nasa.js - https://pastebin.com/HfJqYRNj `nasa.js`
starfield.js - https://pastebin.com/7CdNngU3 `starfield.js`
The python code - https://pastebin.com/0gbxQmu3 `main.py`

Any advice would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
regards,
        Charan Napa

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render JS files using flask or if you can it will certainly not be recommended.

I also went through your index.js,
There were 2 main errors which I noticed:

```
<script src="nasa.js"></script>
<script src="starfield.js"></script>
```

In a flask application, you should never give src like that. You should have a static folder in which there is a js folder where you store all your js files.

Your `<script>` should look like this:

```
<script src="url_for('static', filename='js/nasa.js')">
<script src="url_for('static', filename='js/starfield.js')">
```

And in your python file you should have a `render_template`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True)
```

Make sure you have a folder called templates in which you have your index.html and your static folder.

Comment: I tried rendering files but it simply doesn't work
Do you have any other ways
Thankyou for helping me